# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'login' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, xhtml

I am working on a Register page for my website. When I attempt to open it in Firefox, it says:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'login' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 30
```

I do not understand what it means by this

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include("/session.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Register | McWarfare</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
        <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
            <div id="pageContent">
            <table bgcolor="#bbbbbb" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
            <td width="10%" valign="top" align="center">
            <?php
            if($session->logged_in){
            echo "<h1>Registered</h1>";
            echo "<p>We're sorry <b>$session->username</b>, but you're already registered. "

            }

            else if(isset($_SESSION['regsuccess'])){

            if($_SESSION['regsuccess']){
            echo "<p>Congratulations <b>".$_SESSION['reguname']."</b>, your account was successfully created! "
            }

            else{
            echo "<h1>Registration Failed</h1>";
            echo "<p>We're sorry <b>".$_SESSION['reguname']."</b>, "
            .", but your request could not be completed.<br>Please try again at a later time.</p>";
            }
            unset($_SESSION['regsuccess']);
            unset($_SESSION['reguname']);
            }

            else{
            ?>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <?php
            if($form->num_errors > 0){
            echo "<td><font size=\"2\" color=\"#ff0000\">".$form->num_errors." error(s) found</font></td>";
            }
        ?>
        <form action="process.php" method="POST">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Username:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="user" maxlength="16" value="<?php echo $form->value("user"); ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $form->error("user"); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Password:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $form->value("pass"); ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $form->error("pass"); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Email:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $form->value("email"); ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $form->error("email"); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right">
                        <input type="hidden" name="subjoin" value="1">
                        <input type="submit" value="Register!">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left">Back to <a href="/login">login</a> page.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </td>
    </table>
    </div>
    <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following code is for session.php as requested by @Phil. If you need any other files, just ask.

```
<?php
include("/database.php");
include("/mailer.php");
include("/form.php");

class Session
{
   var $username;
   var $userid;
   var $userlevel;
   var $time;
   var $logged_in;
   var $userinfo = array();
   var $url;
   var $referrer;

   function Session(){
      $this->time = time();
      $this->startSession();
   }

   function startSession(){
      global $database;
      session_start();

      $this->logged_in = $this->checkLogin();

      if(!$this->logged_in){
         $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = GUEST_NAME;
         $this->userlevel = GUEST_LEVEL;
         $database->addActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $this->time);
      }

      else{
         $database->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
      }

      $database->removeInactiveUsers();
      $database->removeInactiveGuests();

      if(isset($_SESSION['url'])){
         $this->referrer = $_SESSION['url'];
      }else{
         $this->referrer = "/";
      }

      $this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   }

   function checkLogin(){
      global $database;

      if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname']) && isset($_COOKIE['cookid'])){
         $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['cookname'];
         $this->userid   = $_SESSION['userid']   = $_COOKIE['cookid'];
      }

      if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['userid']) &&
         $_SESSION['username'] != GUEST_NAME){
         if($database->confirmUserID($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['userid']) != 0){
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['userid']);
            return false;
         }

         $this->userinfo  = $database->getUserInfo($_SESSION['username']);
         $this->username  = $this->userinfo['username'];
         $this->userid    = $this->userinfo['userid'];
         $this->userlevel = $this->userinfo['userlevel'];
         return true;
      }

      else{
         return false;
      }
   }

   function login($subuser, $subpass, $subremember){
      global $database, $form;

      $field = "user";
      if(!$subuser || strlen($subuser = trim($subuser)) == 0){
         $form->setError($field, "* Username not entered");
      }
      else{
         if(!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])*$/i", $subuser)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
         }
      }

      $field = "pass";
      if(!$subpass){
         $form->setError($field, "* Password not entered");
      }

      if($form->num_errors > 0){
         return false;
      }

      $subuser = stripslashes($subuser);
      $result = $database->confirmUserPass($subuser, md5($subpass));

      if($result == 1){
         $field = "user";
         $form->setError($field, "* Username not found");
      }
      else if($result == 2){
         $field = "pass";
         $form->setError($field, "* Invalid password");
      }

      if($form->num_errors > 0){
         return false;
      }

      $this->userinfo  = $database->getUserInfo($subuser);
      $this->username  = $_SESSION['username'] = $this->userinfo['username'];
      $this->userid    = $_SESSION['userid']   = $this->generateRandID();
      $this->userlevel = $this->userinfo['userlevel'];

      $database->updateUserField($this->username, "userid", $this->userid);
      $database->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
      $database->removeActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

      if($subremember){
         setcookie("cookname", $this->username, time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
         setcookie("cookid",   $this->userid,   time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
      }

      return true;
   }

   function logout(){
      global $database;

      if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname']) && isset($_COOKIE['cookid'])){
         setcookie("cookname", "", time()-COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
         setcookie("cookid",   "", time()-COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
      }

      unset($_SESSION['username']);
      unset($_SESSION['userid']);

      $this->logged_in = false;

      $database->removeActiveUser($this->username);
      $database->addActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $this->time);

      $this->username  = GUEST_NAME;
      $this->userlevel = GUEST_LEVEL;
   }

   function register($subuser, $subpass, $subemail){
      global $database, $form, $mailer;

      $field = "user";
      if(!$subuser || strlen($subuser = trim($subuser)) == 0){
         $form->setError($field, "* Username not entered");
      }
      else{
         $subuser = stripslashes($subuser);
         if(strlen($subuser) < 5){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username below 5 characters");
         }
         else if(strlen($subuser) > 30){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username above 30 characters");
         }
         else if(!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])+$/i", $subuser)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
         }
         else if(strcasecmp($subuser, GUEST_NAME) == 0){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username reserved word");
         }
         else if($database->usernameTaken($subuser)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username already in use");
         }
         else if($database->usernameBanned($subuser)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username banned");
         }
      }

      $field = "pass";
      if(!$subpass){
         $form->setError($field, "* Password not entered");
      }
      else{
         $subpass = stripslashes($subpass);
         if(strlen($subpass) < 4){
            $form->setError($field, "* Password too short");
         }
         else if(!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])+$/i", ($subpass = trim($subpass)))){
            $form->setError($field, "* Password not alphanumeric");
         }

      }

      $field = "email";
      if(!$subemail || strlen($subemail = trim($subemail)) == 0){
         $form->setError($field, "* Email not entered");
      }
      else{
         $regex = "/^[_+a-z0-9-]+(\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*"
                 ."@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{1,})*"
                 ."\.([a-z]{2,}){1}$/i";
         if(!preg_match($regex,$subemail)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Email invalid");
         }
         $subemail = stripslashes($subemail);
      }

      if($form->num_errors > 0){
         return 1;
      }
      else{
         if($database->addNewUser($subuser, md5($subpass), $subemail)){
            if(EMAIL_WELCOME){
               $mailer->sendWelcome($subuser,$subemail,$subpass);
            }
            return 0;
         }else{
            return 2;
         }
      }
   }

   function editAccount($subcurpass, $subnewpass, $subemail){
      global $database, $form;
      if($subnewpass){
         $field = "curpass";
         if(!$subcurpass){
            $form->setError($field, "* Current Password not entered");
         }
         else{
            $subcurpass = stripslashes($subcurpass);
            if(strlen($subcurpass) < 4 ||
               !preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])+$/i", ($subcurpass = trim($subcurpass)))){
               $form->setError($field, "* Current Password incorrect");
            }
            if($database->confirmUserPass($this->username,md5($subcurpass)) != 0){
               $form->setError($field, "* Current Password incorrect");
            }
         }

         $field = "newpass";
         $subpass = stripslashes($subnewpass);
         if(strlen($subnewpass) < 4){
            $form->setError($field, "* New Password too short");
         }
         else if(!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])+$/i", ($subnewpass = trim($subnewpass)))){
            $form->setError($field, "* New Password not alphanumeric");
         }
      }
      else if($subcurpass){
         $field = "newpass";
         $form->setError($field, "* New Password not entered");
      }

      $field = "email";
      if($subemail && strlen($subemail = trim($subemail)) > 0){
         $regex = "/^[_+a-z0-9-]+(\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*"
                 ."@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{1,})*"
                 ."\.([a-z]{2,}){1}$/i";
         if(!preg_match($regex,$subemail)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Email invalid");
         }
         $subemail = stripslashes($subemail);
      }

      if($form->num_errors > 0){
         return false;
      }

      if($subcurpass && $subnewpass){
         $database->updateUserField($this->username,"password",md5($subnewpass));
      }

      if($subemail){
         $database->updateUserField($this->username,"email",$subemail);
      }

      return true;
   }

   function isAdmin(){
      return ($this->userlevel == ADMIN_LEVEL ||
              $this->username  == ADMIN_NAME);
   }

   function generateRandID(){
      return md5($this->generateRandStr(16));
   }

   function generateRandStr($length){
      $randstr = "";
      for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
         $randnum = mt_rand(0,61);
         if($randnum < 10){
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+48);
         }else if($randnum < 36){
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+55);
         }else{
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+61);
         }
      }
      return $randstr;
   }
};

$session = new Session;

$form = new Form;

?>
```

Comment: Which one is line 30? What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem?  Have you searched for the error on the internet and on SO to figure out what it could be?

Comment: @Charles I googled the error, and could not find anything related to my situation. I have tried removing certain parts, replacing with others etc. incase I have put an extra ' or something, and all has failed. 

Line 30 is a }

Comment: You have many `echo`s without `;` on the end.

Comment: **Watch out!**  That code you provided is a copy-paste from someone's horrible little PHP tutorial.  It's full of outdated code and bad practices.  Ditch it and never visit the site you got it from again.

Answer (score 3):

Add semicolon to end of these lines:

```
echo "<p>We're sorry <b>$session->username...
```

and

```
echo "<p>Congratulations <b>".$_SESSION...
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Although, now I'm getting the error of "Notice: Undefined variable: session in /var/www/html/register.php on line 20 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/register.php on line 20 and 45."

Comment: Do you know what you are doing? ;) What is the source of session.php?

Comment: @Phil I know xhtml and css, but I'm trying to learn javascript and PHP. What better way to learn than ask questions?

Comment: @Phil I put it in the post.